# How to create multple plots with one DF

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with 3 columns (code, date and value) and i need to create a linear plot for each code (about 50 codes).
I'm not looking for a single plot, but for multiple plot. For example:

```
code = ['DB1', 'DB1', 'DB1', 'DB2', 'DB2', 'DB2', 'DB3', 'DB3', 'DB3']
date = ['2020-02-27', '2020-02-26', '2020-02-25', '2020-02-27', '2020-02-26', '2020-02-25', '2020-02-27', '2020-02-26', '2020-02-25']
value = [10, 20, 30, 11, 12, 13, 40, 50, 60]
```

I'm trying with this:

```
plt.plot(code, date, value, color = "black", linestyle = "solid")
```

but i need to create one plot for each code and not one plot for all codes

Comment: Please include a minimal working example of the code you use.

Comment: I'm trying with this: 
'plt.plot(code, date, value, color = "black", linestyle = "solid")' but i need to create one plot for each code and not one plot for all codes

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're running the code in a jupyter notebook.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"code":code, "date":date, "value":value})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.groupby('code').plot(x='date', y='value')
```

This will create 3 plots; one for each code group.

Comment: This is the output:'Empty DataFrame
                             Columns: [ ]
                             Index: [ ] '    What's wrong?

Comment: Please edit your answer with a textual explanation of your code